Is eating onion and garlic sin?
Onion and Garlic are not eaten by staunch vaishanvites.
I want to know if eating them is sin ?

Related
Related2

According to Vedas and Purānas, Rajas and Tamas Gunas are destructive to human nature and bring you closer to Māyā which is not the real world. Consuming onion and garlic brings you close to Māyā and Rajas and Tamas Gunas start dominating your nature over Sattva Guna.
In Yoga, Rajasic and tamasic foods are also not used because they are detrimental to meditation and devotions. "Garlic and onions are both rajasic and tamasic, and are forbidden to yogis because they root the consciousness more firmly in the body".
Various Smritis and Purānas ban the usage of onion and garlic along with many other vegetables in everyday meals and Naivedya (नैवेद्य/Offering of eatables presented to Deity). If it was forbidden in daily life of dvijas (द्विज/Twice-Born) it is obvious it is forbidden in temples.
I) Manu Smriti Section 5 Verse 5 says:

लशुनं गृञ्जनं चैव पलाण्डुं कवकानि च । अभक्ष्याणि द्विजातीनाममेध्यप्रभवानि च ॥ ५ ॥
laśunaṃ gṛñjanaṃ caiva palāṇḍuṃ kavakāni ca | abhakṣyāṇi dvijātīnāmamedhyaprabhavāni ca || 5 ||
Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and all that proceeds from impure things, are unfit to be eaten by twice-born men.
Note that 'Abhakshya' means 'forbidden' or food that is not meant to be eaten.
— Manu Smriti 5.5.

II) Kūrma Purāna Vol-2 Chapter-17

वृन्ताकं जालिका शाकं कुसुम्भाश्मन्तकं तथा। १८॥ पलाण्डु लसुनं सूक्तं निर्यासं चैव वर्जयेत्।
छन्राकं विड्वराहञ्च शैलं पीयूषमेव च॥ १९॥ विलयं सुमुखजैव कवकानि च वर्जयेत्।
The brinjals, the vegetables, safflower, asmantaka (a kind of plant), onion, garlic, sour articles, the gum of the trees, should not be accepted.
Similarly, the mushrooms, the village boar, Sleymantaka fruit, bee stings, or the milk of a cow during the first seven days of calving, the eatables named Simukha, and the mushroom, should be discarded.

III) In Bhagavath Gita [Śhraddhā Traya Vibhāga Yoga: Chapter 17, Verse 9] Lord Krishna says to avoid food that causes vrittis of Rajoguna as below:

कट्वम्ललवणात्युष्णतीक्ष्णरूक्षविदाहिन: |
आहारा राजसस्येष्टा दु:खशोकामयप्रदा: || 9||
kaṭv-amla-lavaṇāty-uṣhṇa- tīkṣhṇa-rūkṣha-vidāhinaḥ
āhārā rājasasyeṣhṭā duḥkha-śhokāmaya-pradāḥ
Foods that are too bitter, too sour, salty, very hot, pungent, dry, and full of chillies, are dear to persons in the mode of passion. Such foods produce pain, grief, and disease..

When vegetarian foods are cooked with excessive chilies, sugar, salt, etc. they become rājasic. While describing them, the word “very” can be added to all the adjectives used. Thus, rājasic foods are very bitter, very sour, very salty, very hot, very pungent, very dry, full of chillies, etc. They produce ill-health, agitation, and despair. Persons in the mode of passion find such foods attractive, but those in the mode of goodness find them disgusting. The purpose of eating is not to relish bliss through the palate, but to keep the body healthy and strong. As the old adage states: “Eat to live; do not live to eat.” Thus, the wise partake of foods that are conducive to good health, and have a peaceable impact upon the mind i.e., sāttvic foods.
Conclusion:
Therefore, garlic and onion fall in the category of foods that produces vrttis of Rajoguna and Tamoguna in the mind which will diminish the influence of Sattva guna that hinders the observance of Sanātana Dharma (सनातन धर्म).

For twice born men (or Dvijas) onion and garlic are considered as forbidden foods.

Manu Smriti 5.5. Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and (all plants),
springing from impure (substances), are unfit to be eaten by
twice-born men.
5.19. A twice-born man who knowingly eats mushrooms, a village-pig, garlic, a village-cock, onions, or leeks, will become an outcast.

So,for Dvijas, it is a sin as loss of caste is occurring due to consumption of those two items but we can't clearly say in case of the non Dvijas.

What is Twice Born ?

@SpiritualSeeker Those who undergone upanayana ceremony

I thought, initiated folks(including upanayana).

Firstly thanks for posting your questions in the forum.
In Ayurveda, foods are categorized based on their taste (rasa), aftertaste (vipak), energy (virya), and unique qualities (prabhava).
Now, Onion and garlic are believed to have qualities that promote anger.
And according to Bhagavad Gita.Chapter 2, Verse 63
क्रोधाद्भवति सम्मोह: सम्मोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रम: |
स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति
Anger leads to clouding of judgment, which results in bewilderment of memory. When memory is bewildered, the intellect gets destroyed; and when the intellect is destroyed, one is ruined.
That can be one of the reason to avoid onion and garlic as edible in daily life.
